# Do Lasombra show up in cameras?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In Vampire the Masquerade, a member of the Lasombra Clan does not have a reflection. In previous versions of V:tM, this also lead to them not showing up in cameras, if I recall correctly.

Does the no-camera ruling still apply in V20?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No, it never applied

The weakness is still the same (see p59 of V20). So at first I thought that it would depend upon the type [camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera) used. But the comment of [T.J.L](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/22138/t-j-l) was a trigger to dig deeper:

> Cameras do not use reflections to take pictures. SLR cameras use mirrors to change the axis of the image coming in through the lens and direct it up to the viewfinder. When the shutter is triggered, the mirrors move out of the way to expose the film (or CCD) to the light coming in through the lens. If the restriction is specifically mirrors, then you would not be able to see such a vampire through the viewfinder, but you would be able to take a picture of them, regardless of the camera (assuming it was pointed in the right direction anyway).

From my digging through how cameras work, it seems that the vast majority of modern (like the last 20ish years) cameras (film; digital will never have an issue) would have no problem with taking pictures of vampires.

This whole no-camera rules doesn't seem to have a firm real-world basis. I presume this urban myth was launched to help protect the Masquerade in case of accidental pictures.

Comment: Cameras do not use reflections to take pictures. SLR cameras use mirrors to change the axis of the image coming in through the lens and direct it up to the viewfinder. When the shutter is triggered, the mirrors move out of the way to expose the film (or CCD) to the light coming in through the lens.

If the restriction is specifically mirrors, then you would not be able to see such a vampire through the viewfinder, but you _would_ be able to take a picture of them, regardless of the camera (assuming it was pointed in the right direction anyway).

Comment: Sounds like that's an alternative answer, TJL.